# Efficiently creating a left/right diff for an ES2015 Set

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to get a diff for 2 sets where the return value is 2 new Sets: values unique to the left param, and values unique to the right.

For example:

```
const left = new Set([1,2,3]);
const right = new Set([2,3,4]);

const {diffLeft, diffRight} = makeDiff(left, right);
console.log(diffLeft); // Set{1}
console.log(diffRight); // Set{4};
```

My naive solution:

```
const makeDiff = (left, right) => {
  const diffLeft = diff1Side(left, right);
  const diffRight = diff1Side(right, left);
  return {diffLeft, diffRight}
};

const diff1Side = (a,b) => {
  const uniqueDiff = new Set();
  for (let val of a) {
    if (!b.has(val)) {
      uniqueDiff.add(val)
    }
  }
  return uniqueDiff;
};
```

My solution works, but it's slow. Given the constraint that I can only destroy the `left`, I could remove intersections from it during the first iteration to make the 2nd iteration faster, but destruction within a `for...of` gets messy. A second alternative would be to create a superset of left & right & iterate through it, but that is even slower. Any thoughts?

Comment: How slow is "slow"? The complexity of your solution is `O(n+m)`, it won't really get any better than that.

Comment: too slow for something that's runs repeatedly & with Sets that can approach ~100k. you're absolutely correct in the time complexity, but since my sets usually have about a 90-100% intersection, I think I can do better. For example, if I ran through backwards & destroyed matches as I went along, it'd approach `O(n)`.

Comment: What is building those sets? How are you doing this "repeatedly", (how) do the sets change from iteration to iteration? I don't think the problem can be solved without looking at every single set element, if the two sets are the only input to your function.

Comment: If we have *l*eft, *r*ight and *b*oth (where `n=l+b` and `m=r+b`), then `O(l+b+r) = O(l+2b+r)` is still the same as `O(n+m)`. It won't get drastically better than what you have, even with a more clever implementation.

Comment: another way to look at this, is you want to remove from each set values that are in both. so, `if (b.has(val)) { b.delete(val); a.delete(val) }`

Comment: Sets are derived from an immutable object, so this is probably the easiest place to make some gains if I can. I don't get your comment about `O(l+b+r) = O(l+2b+r)`, could you explain why b === 2b?

Comment: Constants are irrelevant in Big O notation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Multiplication_by_a_constant

Comment: @Hamms, I'm constrained to only destroying the `left` :-(. I mean, I could destroy both, but then I'd have to do some reassembly.

Comment: ah, so something like `rightUniques = new Set(); for (let val of right) { if (left.has(val)) { left.delete(val) } else { rightUniques.add(val) } }; return {left, rightUniques };`

Comment: Yep, that looks like the best I can hope for. Thanks!